# Is data on Azure temporary storage private?

Tags: azure, iaas

A follow on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18476408/738851) question.

I understand that the temporary storage is liable to disappear, so I shouldn't use it to store anything I can't retrieve from elsewhere. My question is whether the temporary storage is any more or less private compared to primary storage.

As it's used for swap files, I'd assume that it is secure, but that's purely a guess.

If my VMs get moved, could someone else somehow recover my data from their own temporary storage?

Answer (score 1):

Your VM can't be moved while it's running, therefore the temporary storage will be reset before you VM is moved.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn133149.aspx:

> Management tasks such as a change to the virtual machine size, reset the D: drive

No D: will be given to another customer with data on it, they get a D: drive with a swap file and x GB of free space.